# Ignore matplotlib cursor widget when toolbar widget selected?

Tags: python, matplotlib, interactive

I am using a cursor widget in an interactive Matplotlib plot like so:

```
cursor = Cursor(ax1, useblit=True, color='red', linewidth=1)
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_click)
```

Works well.  The `on_click` function takes the x,y click locations and does some supplemental plotting.  Basic stuff.

When I activate the zoom tool I am also capturing the click.  Is it necessary to bind an activate and deactivate key stroke to the widget a la the RectangleSelector example or does a method exist that knows the state of the toolbar items?

Example of the selector on/off from the RectangleSelector example:

```
def toggle_selector(event):
    if event.key in ['Q','q'] and toggle_selector.RS.active:
        toggle_selector.RS.set_active(False)
    if event.key in ['A', 'a'] and not toggle_selector.RS.active:
        toggle_selector.RS.set_active(True)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That isn't public state, but you can check

```
fig.canvas.manager.toolbar._active is None
```

which will be `True` if the toolbar is not trying to grab clicks (either through pan or zoom).

You are reaching in and touching internal state which can change at any time, so use this at your own risk.  The developers have no compunction about changing anything that starts with a `_*` with no deprecation period.

Comment: Thanks.  Checking `if fig.canvas.manager.toolbar._active is not None: ignore_custom_cursor_clicks`.  Any chance that, as Matplotlib increases interactivity, public access will be made available?

Comment: There is actually a push to re write the tool bar going on now.  You should create an issue I github asking for this.  Include @tacaswell in the text so I get pinged

Comment: Any update on there being a public method for this, since the question in 2013?

Comment: There is a draft version of the new tool bar which shipped with 1.5, but it only supports gtk.  There is a major re-writing of the GUI classel sitting in review that is blocking building out the new toolbar on the other backends.  Getting the GUI changes reviewed is a priority for 2.1 (late summer / early fall 2016)

Comment: for matplotlib version 3.3 and above see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63447351/3944322)

Answer (score 3):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20712813/3944322) doesn't work anymore for matplotlib version 3.3 due to [this commit](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/commit/2d41a724aa711decceba1a1df3fa167c585fbdaa). When using the standard [`NavigationToolbar2`](https://matplotlib.org/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.NavigationToolbar2) you could use its [`mode`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/71de09a8478bc3f4e901a2a7ccb25e1cf4a067a9/lib/matplotlib/backend_bases.py#L2779) property instead.

Example similar to [ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57725073/3944322):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def on_click(evt):
    state = fig.canvas.manager.toolbar.mode
    if state == '':
        print("no tool selected")
    else:
        print(f"{state} selected")

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_click)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the `toolmanager` toolbar is available for more backends now, it might be useful here.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'toolmanager'

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def on_click(evt):
    state = fig.canvas.manager.toolbar.toolmanager.active_toggle["default"]
    if state is None:
        print("no tool selected")
    else:
        print(f"{state} selected")

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_click)

plt.show()
```